firebaseプッシュ通知の失敗
Firebase Admin SDKを使用して、プッシュ通知を試みていますが，通知が届きません。
"Requested entity was not found" エラーが発生します。
サブスクライブにはServiceWorkerを使用しており、返却されるエンドポイントが
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send となります。
HTTP v1 移行後のURL https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/myproject-ID/messages:send が返却されるようになれば、プッシュ通知が成功すると予測しています。
サブスクライブ時のエンドポイント変更方法を教えていただきたいです。
試したこと:
サブスクライブ時のオプションapplicationServerKeyには、ウェブプッシュ証明書のキーを設定しています。
OAuth 2.0 アクセストークンに変更しましたが、サブスクライブに失敗します。
